# Git. Зачем нужно индексирование?

Tags: git

Перед тем как закоммитить изменение, мы должны проиндексировать измененные файлы. Почему индексирование вынесено в отдельную функцию? Почему бы просто нельзя было осуществить индексирование непосредственно при самом коммите?

Comment: Чтобы коммитить изменения частично, например.

Comment: У некоторых клиентов, например, TortoiseGit, индексирование осуществляется именно перед коммитом. Для тех, кому индекс не интересен это несколько удобнее.

Answer (score 6):

Это сделано для того, что бы иметь возможность управлять содержимым коммита.

Не всегда требуется фиксировать все изменения сразу, т.к. они могут быть логически слабо связаны, содержать решение более одной проблемы.

Comment: на самом деле не совсем согласен что для этого, так как мы в коммите с таким же успехом могли просто выбрать часть файлов и просто закоммитить. Но нам нужен всегда сначала проиндексовать.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Так индекс это и есть «выбрать часть файлов». И вообще есть шорткаты типа флага `-a` или просто перечисления нужных файлов при коммите.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov бывает, что изменения даже в одном файле стоит распихать по нескольким коммитам

Comment: да, но для примера, если я выберу файл и проиндексирую его, потом снова этот файл изменю, то при коммите файл выбран, но в коммите новых изменений не будет. Надо *СНОВА* индексировать его, чтобы закоммитить изменения, но ведь он у меня уже выбран был.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov всё правильно, именно так и должно быть :)

Comment: @Alexcei Shmakov А для чего вам добавлять изменения в индекс и не коммитить их? Такое ощущение, что что-то вы делаете не так. Индексируйте изменения непосредственно для того, чтобы включить их в коммит - не имеет смысла делать это заранее, когда вам еще не известно какие изменения в него попадут в итоге.

Comment: @Ovsyanka, вы уж простите меня, но если вы это не делали, то это не значит это не имеет смысла. Простой пример, я готов к коммиту, все проиндексировал, но решил еще раз проревьювить свой код, и вижу, что вместо а у меня b, либо банально опечатка в комментарии, съехала разметка.. и тд. Ситуации редкие, но в жизни встречающиеся. И для программистов в командах, которые не понимают как работает гит, это неожиданность.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Это было мое субъективное мнение. Я не понимаю сейчас какую мысль вы хотели донести. Такое ощущение, что вы считаете этап индексации лишним и усложняющим жизнь. Если это так - представьте как бы вы делили на коммиты большое кол-во изменений без этапа индексации. А обсуждение того, как правильно пользоваться индексацией может стать слишком длинным, так что если есть желание - можем продолжить в чате (https://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Ovsyanka, да, действительно я сначала так посчитал, что индексирование лишнее со стороны пользователя, что это всего лишь дела внутренностей гита. И попытался эту тему поднять в комментариях, и убедился в том числе для себя, что без индексов было бы плохо. И вопрос вроде бы исчерпал себя. Но вы дальше подняли вопрос, что я как будто бы(не знаю откуда вы это взяли) что-то делаю не так и посоветовали индексировать перед самым коммитом. Но это неверно. Изменения в одном файле можно распихнуть по нескольким комитам и можно индексировать "по середине" процесса разработки. Вот и все :)

Answer (score 3):

Вы не должны. Но очевидно, что так делается для удобства. Можете делать

```
git commit -a
```

В индекс автоматически добавятся все изменения. Или

```
git commit --interactive
```

Или

```
git commit --patch
```

Тогда сможете выбирать нужные файлы по-одному, как вам и хочется.

Всё это написано в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Сдается мне, что сделано это было для того, чтобы не вводить дополнительную сущность "список добавленных, но не закоммиченных файлов".

В svn, например, список файлов и их содержимое хранятся порознь. Поэтому можно сначала заполнить просто список, а потом, при коммите, записать само содержимое.

В git же, коммит, через хэши, содержит и сами файлы. Сделать индекс таким же было просто удобно для программистов, писавших git. Пользователям это доставляет не слишком много неудобств, но при этом дает некоторые преимущества в виде неполного коммита файла.